# java error, Class Mobile is already defined in package unamed package

Tags: java

Hi I am trying to get my code to create the two new constructor objects which i reqiure

why am i getting this error?, java error, Class Mobile is already defined in package unamed package

Error comes up at public class mobile at the bottom of the page

**UPDATE** 
I have just renamed the second public class to mymobile instead of mobile, and have left the main public class as just Mobile (as i am doing an assignment and it says the first public class has to be named  public class mobile), however i now get this error: constructor Mobile in class Mobile cannot be applied to given types.

```
/**
 * to write a simple java class Mobile that models a mobile phone.
 * 
 * @author (ME) 
 * @version (14/10/13)
 */
public class Mobile

{
    // type of phone
    private int phonetype;
    // size of screen in inches
    private int screensize;
    // menory card capacity
    private int memorycardcapacity;
    // name of present service provider
    private int serviceprovider;
    // type of contract with service provider
    private int typeofcontract;
    // camera resolution in megapixels
    private int cameraresolution;
    // the percentage of charge left on the phone
    private int checkcharge;
    // wether the phone has GPS or not
    private int GPS;
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int x;


   // The constructor method
   public Mobile (String Mobilephonetype, String Mobilescreensize, String Mobilememorycardcapacity, String Mobilecameraresolution, String MobileGPS, String Mobileserviceprovider, String Mobiletypeofcontract, String Mobilecheckcharge)
   {
     this.phonetype = phonetype;
     this.screensize = screensize;
     this.memorycardcapacity = memorycardcapacity;
     this.cameraresolution = cameraresolution;
     this.GPS = GPS;
     this.serviceprovider = serviceprovider;
     this.typeofcontract = typeofcontract;
     this.checkcharge = checkcharge;

   }

   // The new constructor method
    {
     this.phonetype = phonetype;
     this.screensize = screensize;
     this.memorycardcapacity = memorycardcapacity;
     this.cameraresolution = cameraresolution;
     this.GPS = GPS;
     this.serviceprovider = serviceprovider;
     this.typeofcontract = typeofcontract;
     this.checkcharge = checkcharge;
    }
     // A method to display the state of the object to the screen
   public void displayMobileDetails()
   {
     System.out.println("phonetype: " + phonetype);
     System.out.println("screensize: " + screensize);
     System.out.println("memorycardcapacity: " + memorycardcapacity);
     System.out.println("cameraresolution: " + cameraresolution);
     System.out.println("GPS: " + GPS);

    }

     public class myMobile {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

     Mobile Samsung = new Mobile("Samsung", "3.0", "4gb", "8mega pixels","GPS" );
     Mobile Blackberry = new Mobile("Blackberry", "3.0", "4gb", "8mega pixels","GPS" );
     Samsung.displayMobileDetails();
     Blackberry.displayMobileDetails();
   }




   }
 }


any replies/answers would be greatly appreciated, thanks
```

Comment: Because you have two classes named `Mobile`. You did read the error message, right..?

Comment: Check the line "public class Mobile {" which is a second time in the middle of your code. You also pasted the constructor code twice, which should actually lead to another compiler error.

Comment: Several issues with your current code (a) Your Mobile code takes 6 arguments and you are passing in only 5 when constructing the object (b) In your constructor you are not setting the fields to the value of what you are passing in to the constructor (you are just setting the field to itself, for example this.phoneType = phoneType is the same as this.phoneType = this.phoneType) (c) In your constructor you are taking in Strings presumably to set the field values. However all your fields are ints, you may want to change that.

Answer (score 0):

you can not have two class with same name in a same package

try changing one of your class name

```
public class Mobile {...}

public class Test {    
   public static void main(String[] args) {.... }

}
```

=====================================================

**update**

try the below code

```
public class Mobile

{
    // type of phone
    private int phonetype;
    // size of screen in inches
    private int screensize;
    // menory card capacity
    private int memorycardcapacity;
    // name of present service provider
    private int serviceprovider;
    // type of contract with service provider
    private int typeofcontract;
    // camera resolution in megapixels
    private int cameraresolution;
    // the percentage of charge left on the phone
    private int checkcharge;
    // wether the phone has GPS or not
    private int GPS;
    // instance variables - replace the example below with your own
    private int x;

    // The constructor method
    public Mobile(String Mobilephonetype, String Mobilescreensize,
            String Mobilememorycardcapacity, String Mobilecameraresolution,
            String MobileGPS, String Mobileserviceprovider,
            String Mobiletypeofcontract, String Mobilecheckcharge) {
        this.phonetype = phonetype;
        this.screensize = screensize;
        this.memorycardcapacity = memorycardcapacity;
        this.cameraresolution = cameraresolution;
        this.GPS = GPS;
        this.serviceprovider = serviceprovider;
        this.typeofcontract = typeofcontract;
        this.checkcharge = checkcharge;

    }

    // A method to display the state of the object to the screen
    public void displayMobileDetails() {
        System.out.println("phonetype: " + phonetype);
        System.out.println("screensize: " + screensize);
        System.out.println("memorycardcapacity: " + memorycardcapacity);
        System.out.println("cameraresolution: " + cameraresolution);
        System.out.println("GPS: " + GPS);

    }

    public Mobile(String Mobilephonetype, String Mobilescreensize,
            String Mobilememorycardcapacity, String Mobilecameraresolution,
            String MobileGPS) {
        this.phonetype = phonetype;
        this.screensize = screensize;
        this.memorycardcapacity = memorycardcapacity;
        this.cameraresolution = cameraresolution;
        this.GPS = GPS;

    }

}

 class mymobile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mobile Samsung = new Mobile("Samsung", "3.0", "4gb", "8mega pixels",
                "GPS");
        Mobile Blackberry = new Mobile("Blackberry", "3.0", "4gb",
                "8mega pixels", "GPS");
        Samsung.displayMobileDetails();
        Blackberry.displayMobileDetails();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi I have renamed the second public class to mymobile instead of mobile, and have left the main public class as just Mobile (as i am doing an assignment and it says the first public class has to be named  public class mobile), however i now get this error: constructor Mobile in class Mobile cannot be applied to given types.

Comment: Hi just tried the updated code and it now says: class mymobile is public, should be declared in a file named mymobile.java

Comment: can you try after  removing the word public from  public class mymobile . updated the code again. and accept the answer if you get the solution

Comment: Hi i have just tried updating with the new code and it says class compiled - no syntax errors :), very much appreciated, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have named you model class as Mobile, and your main class as Mobile too. Rename the main class to something else.